# Netbeans Maven Error

Tags: maven, netbeans

I pulled an old project of mine from github.  Long long time ago, I am trying to run it(it builds fine but will not run) but I keep getting this error Maven error and I am not sure how to fix it.

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project soodooku: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Comment: Try adding `-X` to your command line so that you get a complete stack trace of the failure